# Singleton Class Strict Implementation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, singleton

I am trying to create a singleton class. While searching for related documents, I came across an [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) that gives a strict implementation of a singleton. Where I found the following piece of code:

```
+ (MyGizmoClass*)sharedManager
{
    if (sharedGizmoManager == nil) {
        sharedGizmoManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedGizmoManager;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[self sharedManager] retain];
}
```

Can anyone tell me, why is it necessary to call `+allocWithZone:`?. Why does calling `+alloc` end up in a crash?

Also we've overridden `+allocWithZone:`. Why so? Why cant we override `+alloc` instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you're referencing is pretty old. You could notice a warning when you open it:

> Retired Document
>
> Important: This document may not represent best practices for current development. Links to downloads and other resources may no longer be valid.

IMHO this implementation of singleton is the best option nowadays: https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide#singletons

Comment: But what if the user of our singleton class tries to create an instance using alloc/init instead of using the class method

Comment: There are no public `alloc/init` methods, because singleton can be created only once. The instance can be retrieved only by calling `sharedInstance` class method.

Comment: Even if you override alloc/init to enforce singleton usage, a user can create more instances anyway using NSAllocateObject() and class_createInstance().  So it's not typical to bother doing so anyway. If you want to, though, override alloc to return the sharedManager, and in sharedManager use super alloc.

Comment: Just a query! Cant I use `@synchronized{}` as shown [here](http://xperienced.com.pl/blog/3-ways-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-objective-c)

Comment: You can. But there is some disadvantage in this implementation, try to google

Answer (score 0):

> When one object creates another, it’s sometimes a good idea to make
>   sure they’re both allocated from the same region of memory. The zone
>   method (declared in the NSObject protocol) can be used for this
>   purpose; it returns the zone where the receiver is located.

As *BBum* says:

> The reality, though, is that pretty much nothing uses zones. It was
>   originally intended to give the ability to, say, co-locate all of the
>   objects related to a document in a zone and then bulk destroy them by
>   simply deallocating the zone. In practice, this proved unworkable and
>   zones haven't been used in more than a decade in the OpenStep APIs.

Also in Apple Documentation for [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/allocWithZone%3a):

> This method exists for historical reasons; memory zones are no longer
>   used by Objective-C.

As of now, we use these to create singleton class by using `alloc`.

```
@interface SomeManager : NSObject
    + (MyObject *)singleton;
@end
@implementation SomeManager
    + (MyObject *)singleton {    
         static id singleton = nil; 
         @synchronized([MyObject class]){ 
              if (singleton == nil) { 
                  singleton = [[self alloc] init]; 
              } 
          }
          return singleton;
        }
 @end
```

Comment: then why is that the document makes use of this method and not '+alloc'

Answer (score 0):

As a strict singleton, the class's `init` and `new` can **NEVER** be called, or else a compile-time error should occur. I use `NS_UNAVAILABLE` to hide `init` and `new` completely.

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface My: NSObject
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (instancetype)new NS_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (instancetype)shared;

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger i;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and the implementation file:

```
@implementation My
- (instancetype)initPrivate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Do initialization
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)shared {
    static id _i = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _i = [[My alloc] initPrivate];
    });
    return _i;
}
@end
```

At this time, `init` and `new` will trigger compile-time error

```
My *m = My.new; // Error
My *m1 = [[My alloc] init]; // Error
My.shared.i = 6; // OK
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like that doc is a bit outdated.
Current common practice is using GDC

```
+ (MyGizmoClass *)sharedInstance {
    static MyGizmoClass *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[MyGizmoClass alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: This is for a non-strict implementation of a singleton. It's true that pretty much everyone only uses this technique, but there are times when you need a strict singleton.